# Transact SQL Calculation within group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I want to calculate weights within groups. Say I have a table like this with a group variable and I want to calculate the weight column which is product value over the sum of all product values within this group. How can this be done?

Data example:

I want to go from this table:

[image: Original Table]

To this table:

[image: Table I want to create]

That means the weight column does not exist. The goal is to create a new table that contains all original columns plus a new column called weight.

Weight calculation example: For line 5 group B product x the weight is calculated as weight = 10/40.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a window function to achieve this. Here is an example:

```
SELECT
    1.0 / (SUM([Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Group])) * [Value] AS [Weight]
FROM [YourTable]
```

I suggest that you create a view on top of your existing table (depending on your needs, of course). You can create your view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [YourView] AS
SELECT
    [Group],
    Product,
    [Value],
    CASE 
        WHEN (SUM([Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Group])) = 0 THEN 0 
        ELSE 1.0 / (SUM([Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Group])) * [Value] END AS [Weight] 
FROM [YourTable]
```

Comment: What is if for some groups sum(value) equal to zero? How can we safeguard against this? e.g. filter them out in the calculation?

Comment: You can use a CASE WHEN statement to check whether the group sum is 0 prior to performing the division. I've updated the CREATE VIEW statement in my answer to provide an example on this. I have chosen to return 0 as [Weight] when the SUM for the Group is 0, but you can change this depending on your need.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [group], SUM(weight)
FROM table
GROUP BY [group]
```

In response to your comment - you may create a view which will calculate weight on the fly when you query it:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[GroupWeights]
AS
SELECT [group], SUM(weight)
FROM table
GROUP BY [group]
```

Answer for the recent edits in your question:

```
CREATE VIEW ProductWeights
AS
SELECT [p.group], product, value, (value / (SELECT SUM(value) FROM Products WHERE [group] = [p.group] GROUP BY [group])) AS [weight]
FROM Products AS p
```

Comment: The weight column DOES NOT exist. The goal is to to create the weight column i.e. a new table that will contain the previous columns plus the weight column

Comment: please see my edits this answer does not calculate the weights

Comment: What is if for some groups sum(value) equal to zero? How can we safeguard against this? e.g. filter them out in the calculation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SELECT INTO for creating new table and SUM with partition for getting sum by group as below:

```
Select [Group], Product, [Value], 
   [Weight] = ([Value]*1.0)/SUM([Value]) over(Partition by [Group])
   INTO NewTable from YourTable
```